# Как правильно оформить подключение библиотек в Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, eclipse, gradle

В `Eclipse` у меня так выглядит ситуация с подключенными библиотеками:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Как мне правильно перевести или подключить их в** `gradle`**?**

Моя попытка выглядит следующим образом:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "..."
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 32
        versionName "3.2.2"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile project(':lvl')
    compile files('libs/android.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.5.0'
}
```

Ошибка выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте так убрать "compile files('libs/android.jar')" и из папки `libs` сам этот файл.

Comment: Тогда у меня один из моих классов будет покрыт красными линиями) Он нужен мне для JSONParser'a

Comment: Ну, попробуйте в этом файле всё закомментить... Может тогда всё заработает и вопрос окажется в том как правильно именно парсер подключить?..

Comment: android.jar точно нечего делать в подключаемых библиотеках

Comment: @pavlofff ну в эклипсе он же нашел дело и с ним справляется на ура

Comment: Я не вижу в подключаемых библиотеках (dependencies) вашего проекта Eclipse никакого android.jar. android.jar - это, собственно, фреймворк Android, он есть на всех устройствах без вашего участия/ Если вы поставите в AS отображение для дерева проекта *Project*, то увидите его и сами в секции *External Libraries -> Android API ..*

Comment: @pavlofff спасибо за Вашу помощь! все решилось:)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб и Вам спасибо за помощь, проблема решилась:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался я до конца со своей проблемой.

Как сказали уважаемые @pavlofff и @ЮрийСПб android.jar действительно был лишним. Как только я его снес у меня сразу же выскакивали ошибки на `HttpParams, HttpClient` и т.д. Погуглив, я нашел решение и для этой проблемы:

```
android {
       useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

Вот собственно и все. Проект запустился без проблем:)